# Retrieve Tags From GetPocket API (Python)

Tags: python, api, dictionary, pocket

I have found a lot of documentation and helpful api wrappers for getpocket.com API but I still haven't been able to find a workable answer as to how I can retrieve the tags associated with the articles I have saved.  There are a number of tutorials and wrappers that make it pretty straightforward to connect and retrieve my saved articles but for some reason the tags aren't a key/value pair in the dictionary after I download my info.  It seems a bit silly that those aren't automatically included and from what I've gathered this is an issue from getpocket api directly and not api wrappers available.  Can anyone assist in clarifying how I can get the tags for each saved article using python?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved: [github issue](https://github.com/rakanalh/pocket-api/issues/6)